# notice: array to string conversion in php wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

When I echo `$text` I have this error `array to string conversion.`

How to solve this error?

```
function cd_meta_box_cb()
{
global $post;
$values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
$text = isset( $values['video_meta_box_text'] ) ? $values['video_meta_box_text'] : '';
wp_nonce_field( 'video_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
?>
<p>

    <input type="text" name="video_meta_box_text" id="video_meta_box_text" value="<?php echo $text; ?>" />
</p>
<?php    
}
```

Comment: Difficult to guess based on the information. Try changing `<?php echo $text; ?>` to `<?php print_r($text, true); ?>` dump the contents of `$text` as a value of the `input` element. Once you know the structure of `$text` you would know what to use. Do keep in mind this is only for debugging and should not be used in production.

Comment: In your code the variable `$text` is must be an array. Try `var_dump()` on `$text` to get more debug info.

Comment: I try `var_dupm()` output  `array(1) { [0]=> string(39)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some types are converted to string when printing, such as `integer`, other types require some conversions in order to get a proper string output.

To get a string output of your array you must convert it into a string by yourself.

First, make sure `$text` will always be an array, even an empty one. There are other ways, but I'm keeping to this simple one.

```
$text = isset( $values['video_meta_box_text'] ) ? $values['video_meta_box_text'] : [];
```

Then you can use the `implode()` function to chain all the values into a single string.

```
<input type="text" name="video_meta_box_text" id="video_meta_box_text" value="<?php echo implode(', ', $text); ?>">
```

I've used a `,`  delimiter here but you can you whatever suit you.

**Note** that this way won't work if your array contains values such as objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is saved in an array and you are trying to access it using only the array key.

```
function cd_meta_box_cb() {
   global $post;
   $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );

   //First, check to see if your array is not empty as it may still be set but without a value. Then return th efirst key of the array: [0]
   $text = !empty( $values['video_meta_box_text'] ) ? $values['video_meta_box_text'][0] : '';
   wp_nonce_field( 'video_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
?>
<p>

   <input type="text" name="video_meta_box_text" id="video_meta_box_text" value=" <?php echo $text; ?>" /></p>
<?php    
}
```